# how to get the value of link clicked in commandlink tag in managed beans

Tags: primefaces, download, commandlink

```
<p:commandLink  ajax="false" value="#{eas_details.documentuploadedname}" >

 <p:fileDownload value="#{easdocchecklistinfoMB.file}" />
```

unable to get the value of which link is clicked by user in my mb.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<f:setPropertyActionListener target="" value="">`, which if nested in `<p:commandLink>` or `<p:commandButton>` will inject the a value into the provided target.